# Negative value of $step in range(), PHP

Tags: php

This is taken from the php.net manual for json_decode(), Example 4, 5th line from the bottom there:

```
foreach (range(4, 3, -1) as $depth)
```

I am not sure what is the purpose of that -1 there. I tried range(4, 3, 1) and range (4, 3, -1) and it gives the same results. The 1 in the first example is the default so it could be range(4, 3). I was only trying it with something like print_r(range(4, 3, -1); so the example on the php.net may be a different thing. I was looking on the Net and there is no info about it, or not right away.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php read documentation

Comment: Step should be given as a positive number

Comment: @Aaron Smith:  nothing, step is automatically converted to positive *number*... which means you can set fractional increments too!

Comment: @Sergej: nope, it can be anything that can be cast to a *number*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will actually ignore the sign of the `$step` argument, and determine whether to increment or decrement based purely on whether `$start > $end` or `$end > $start`. For example:

```
<?php print_r( range( 20, 11, 3 ) ); ?>
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 11
)

<?php print_r( range( 11, 20, -3 ) ); ?>
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 20
)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So basically the example on php.net is wrong? I've been testing this too.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php - Example #4, 5th line from the bottom.

Comment: This is made just for readability, since 4>3, and step should be -1.

Answer (score 0):

Step is automatically cast to a positive number (yes, the manual is incorrect here)

So all of these will work:

```
var_dump(
    range(1, 5, 1), // positive integer
    range(1, 5, -1), // negative integer
    range(1, 5, 2), 
    range(1, 5, .5), // positive fractional number
    range(1, 5, "-0.1") // negative fractional number passed as string
);
```

Also, if you use a float value as $step, all the values will be float too, even if they are whole numbers.